# AFNetworking. Отмена текущего запроса

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

Известно, что считается плохим тоном настраивать вручную таймаут соединения для запросов через `AFNetworking`. По словам самого автора: "Запросы могут занимать длительное время на низких скоростях. Лучше доверить `iOS` самостоятельно определять отсутствует ли соединение либо оно слабое и надо подождать"...

Очевидно, что при таком длительном ожидании, пользователь приложения просто напросто нажмет "назад" и скорее всего попробует перезайти на страницу. Одновременно с этим, запустится и второй запрос... а если интернет до сих пор медленный? 4-5 заход будет успешным, но потом один за другим прилетят ответы по таймауту (у меня на них стоят `AlertView`). Это получается 3 раза надо будет закрывать их.

Есть ли команда отмены текущего запроса или же всех запросов `AFNetworking`, чтобы запускать ее каждый раз перед новыми запросами, предотвратив тем самым многократный запуск `AFNetworking`?

Сам запрос вида:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON){ .......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое - это остановить операцию

```
[operation cancel];
```

Чтобы можно было отключать все текущие запросы, нужно их добавлять в `NSOperationQueue`. Затем все запросы можно отменить с помощью `[operationQueue cancelAllOperations]`

Например:

```
operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.ru"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFPropertyListResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id propertyList)
    {
        NSLog(@"Завершено");
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!(error.code == kCFURLErrorCancelled &&
            [error.domain isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain]))
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }
];

[operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

И, как я писал выше:

```
[operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

PS: Условие с `kCFURLErrorCancelled` нужно для того, чтобы отмена запроса не считалась за ошибку.